# Emails sent using SMTP Codeigniter are breaking in different email providers inboxes

Tags: codeigniter, email, outlook, smtp, gmail

I've set up our website to send certain automated emails to users (change password, newsletter subscribe, etc..) using SMTP codeigniter.

Unfortunately, when testing the email received something always messes up, and depending on the provider it's a different issue!

Here is my email.php setting:

```
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtpout.secureserver.net'; //change this
$config['smtp_port'] = '465';
$config['smtp_user'] = 'user@example.com'; //change this
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'password; //change this
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$config['newline'] = "\r\n"; //use double quotes to comply with RFC 822 standard
```

Here is what the person should receive:

```
Hi, Subscription Test User!

Your Subscription has been updated successfully. Please enjoy the features that come with your monthly plan.
If you wish to change or cancel your Subscription, you can do so at any time through your Account Settings.
```

Here is what appears in AOL and GMail

```
    Hi, Subscription%20Test%20User!

Your Subscription has been updated successfully. Please enjoy the features that come with your monthly plan.
If you wish to change or cancel your Subscription, you can do so at any time through your Account Settings.
```

And worse of all, this is appearing in Outlook/Hotmail

```
Hi, Subscription Test User!

=3Cbr />Your Subscription has been=pdated successfully. Please enjoy the feature= that come with your monthly plan.
If you wish to chang= or cancel your Subscription, you can do so at any time through your Accou=t Settings.
```

I don't know how to fix this and would really appreciate any help as to why different email providers are showing these characters replaced like this.
To break it down:

```
**AOL/Gmail:** replaces spaces for {user_name} with %20

**Outlook:** Adds =3Cbr /> and also replaces characters with =
```

Thank you!

Comment: can you provide the raw message content? the content that you use in `$this->email->message($content);`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment.
The line of code you mentioned is not in email.php, where would I typically find that?